# How to manage the size of columns in tkinter Treeview?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I'm having trouble with the end of the columns display. If I push the last one back this happens:

[image: Image 1]

Also, if I push too forward, the last column will disappear:

[image: Image 2]

Is there any wayto fix it?

Comment: You can set the `stretch` option of column 1,2,3 to False and column 4 to True.